# Why doesn't Superman check every lead mine to find Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, injustice

I've been reading the *Injustice* series (of course from Year 1). If I read them correctly, Batman have gone underground for five years without being able to be tracked by Superman. How? By hiding in secret hideout in an Alaskan lead mine. Lead blocks his X-ray vision.

I'm curious why Superman doesn't consider this thing to find Batman. Sure he cannot see through lead, but then again he have an army of superheroes to do his bidding, right?

Comment: How would he find all the lead mines?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Probably he'll tell Cyborg to build drones that try to systematically scan any lead mines from ground? :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are *a lot* of mines in the United States. So many that even if Superman correctly guessed that Batman was in a lead mine (as opposed to just a lead-lined room) and in the United States, it would take him a inordinate amount of time to search through them all, even with his super-speed.

Using [publicly available information from the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/mining/statistics/allmining.html), Superman would know that in 2013 (the year that *Injustice* was first released), there were 349 active metal mines. By going to [AbandonedMines.gov](http://www.abandonedmines.gov/mapdata.html), he could find out that there are approximately 6,830 abandoned [hardrock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_mining_(hard_rock)) mines in Alaska alone, and many more in other US states. Not all of these mines were strictly lead, but some of them were mixed minerals including lead. With many other abandoned mines in other states (e.g. 24,183 in Arizona) there are hundreds of thousands of mines in the United States alone where Batman could be hiding.

And we're just counting ones that were officially registered with the US government; if Batman were hiding in an unauthorized mine, or expanded a mine that was abandoned, then Superman probably wouldn't have any way of knowing that it exists.

Of course, Batman could have also easily been hiding in any of the following places:

- In a lead lined room
- In any mine outside of the United States
- In a place that processes lead (e.g. smelting factory)

Honestly, if Superman were to try checking all of the mines or other places that deal with lead, he would die of boredom long before he actually found Batman.

Comment: Frankly, I think the premise of Batman going into a lead-shielded anything seems a bit unnecessary. Consider how many buildings Superman would have to search even with his X-ray vision if Batman simply chose to move to a random city and stop wearing a bat costume.

Comment: “he would die of boredom” — Superman’s new kryptonite! “No, don’t make me watch *Man of Steel* again!!”

Comment: Well, it seems that I underestimate the brute-force attempt to locate every lead mine...

Comment: @Paul In *For Tomorrow*, Superman can recognize Lois' heart beat from anywhere on Earth/orbit. I'd expect he could recognize Bruce Wayne's face or skeleton.